# Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon 2nd Gen with broken screen - how to get it to use external monitor?

Tags: display, thinkpad, external-display

I've been given an old Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon 2nd Gen which has a broken screen - not physically broken, but it doesn't show an image at all.  It sort of "lights up black" if you know what I mean, rather than being totally dead.

I'm trying to plug it into an external monitor via HDMI, but I can't get the monitor to pick it up.  On my older Thinkpad T430 I can press Fn & F7 to switch between internal/external displays, so I can select the external monitor without having to go through BIOS or any of the gui menus.  The X1 does have one of these, but it's on this "adaptive keyboard" strip, a horrible plastic bar at the top with no feedback at all for whether you've even pressed it: to make matters worse the "switch displays" button (which looks like a projector) is on the second "set" of adaptive keys, where you press the virtual "fn" button in the top left to get there.

[image]

I tried to do it blind via BIOS, by going into BIOS on the X1 and my old T430, and copying the keypresses I was doing on the T430, to choose an external display.  But, that didn't work either - I don't even know if I was in BIOS in the first place:  normally I would hold down f1 but the F1 key is on the adaptive keyboard strip, which I don't even know if it's working.  (I hate this adaptive keyboard strip).

Any ideas, other than buying a new screen?  (I have replaced the screen on my old thinkpad, so i'm not scared of it, I just don't want to spend the £100 when I'm going to be using it with an external monitor anyway).

thanks

Comment: It should have an HDMI connection on the side. My X1 has that. Plug in the monitor and start up / restart.

Comment: Pressing Win+P a couple of times should cycle through options of duplicating to or extending to the external monitor.

Comment: @John - that's what I've done already, used the native HDMI port.

Comment: @Mokubai does it need to have booted into windows to do that?  I don;t know if i'm actually in Windows yet, or sitting on some menu page.  But i'll try it...nope, nothing happened.

Comment: Actually I just noticed that it beeps twice on startup, which a google tells me can mean that it's unable to boot due to a hardware problem...

Comment: It should not beep like that on normal startup. If it is doing that and the external monitor will not work with the HDMI port then the drive may have an error or the OS has been damaged. I am not sure what advice as the X1 machines are tricky to dismantle (having removed the base on my own X1).

Comment: I would open up the display, perhaps it's nothing but a bad connection.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille its sounding like i've nothing to lose, might as well.